# How can I access a HashMap using Expression Language

Tags: el

I'm having some problems on manipulating data in EL / JSP.

I have two variables in my `Action` (I'm using Struts2 btw) they are:

```
private List<Appointment> appointment;
private Map<Integer, String> doctors;
```

Appointment has the attribute `docID` and the doctors list uses this to identify the Doctor full name; I want in my JSP to get the doctor full name. That is, I want this:

```
${doctors[${appointment.docID}]}
```

However this dont work. Any idean on how to get this working?

Comment: See also [Java EE 5 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaim)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to open another EL-expression. Just remove the inner-one:

```
${doctors[appointment.docID]}
```